# Is invoking SwingWorker run a mistake and how to synchronize doInBackground?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I'm using a SwingWorker as a way to wrap non swing tasks/actions with a before and after methods always running in the Event Dispatch Thread (in other words: I invoke before then I invoke an abstract method in the doInBackground and then I invoke after in the done method). This started causing a lot of trouble lately since whatever happens in doInBackground has to be synchronized. I noticed that the problem goes away if I call run instead of execute, but from what I understand the run method works the same as in Thread, it just starts the execution in the exact same thread it has been called from instead of creating a new one, and as such the doInBackground executes on the EDT if I call run from the EDT. Is my thinking correct? How can I synchronize the doInBackground method with the thread calling execute on the worker?

I used the following code but it seems to be creating a thread lock:

```
private Object LOCK = new Object();    

public final void method() {

    someObject.before();

    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker1 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            methodExt();
            return null;
        }

        protected void done() {
            someObject.after();
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    };

    worker1.execute();

    synchronized (LOCK) {
        try {
            LOCK.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, basically, you've circumvented any benefit that the SwingWorker was giving you, as the `LOCK.wait` will block the EDT...  What would be better is using some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which tells you when `done` has been called...I don't know, may like using a `PropertyChangeListener`....?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do not see how a PropertyChangeListener can help me here. I can just invoke someObject.before(); methodExt(); someObject.after();, but then methodExt runs on the EDT which is a mistake, and that is why I'm using the SwingWorker, because it has a straight forward done method which I can use. I mean I can make a new Thread that invokes methodExt() and then in this thread make a new Runnable that invokes someObject.after() and invoke it on the EDT but I think the SwingWorker is a way more elegant aproach.

Comment: But, your LOCK is blocking the EDT...and from memory, you can simply call SwingWorker#get which will block until doInBackground returns...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I understand, I never said it is a good example of code. That's the problem. I need the EDT to wait for a thread that does some calculations without blocking the EDT.

Comment: That's my point, no you don't, you want to use an observer pattern to tell something that the worker has completed

Comment: Now, if you can't design yourself out of this problem, you could take a look at the [foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/introduction.php) API, which allows to wait within the EDT, similar to the way that a modal dialog works

Comment: @Mac you shouldn't ask the EDT to "wait" for anything. If you are thinking about an event handler that does "X, trigger Y, wait for Y to finish, do Z" then the correct architecture is to finish the current handler after "trigger Y" and move Z into another handler that is triggered by Y completing. While Y is running in the background the EDT can deal with other events.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, I understand your logic and I accept it as the right one. I'm unfortunately working in a big pile of code where everything runs on the EDT, and fixing one such problem can lead to many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never block on the EDT.  The whole point of `SwingWorker` is that it allows you to trigger a task to run on a background thread and schedule additional code to run on the EDT after the background job is complete *without* blocking the EDT in the meantime.  So if you want to run `methodA()` on the EDT, then `methodB()` in the background, then `methodC()` back on the EDT after B has completed, the answer is to call `methodC()` from the `done()` method of the `SwingWorker`.

Instead of trying to do

```
doSomething();
method(); // which blocks waiting for the BG task to complete
doSomethingElse();
```

you could modify `method()` to

```
public final void method(final Runnable callback) {

    someObject.before();

    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker1 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            methodExt();
            return null;
        }

        protected void done() {
            someObject.after();
            if(callback != null) callback.run();
        }
    };

    worker1.execute();
}
```

and then call it as

```
doSomething();
method(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
});
```

Now `method` returns immediately and does not block the EDT, but `doSomethingElse` still happens on the EDT after the background task is complete.